# SQL 2008 Subtract

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to subtract the two sum at the end of this query

```
SELECT T0.[DocNum],T0.[CardCode], T0.[CardName], 
T1.[ItemCode], T1.[Dscription], T1.[Quantity], T1.[Price],T0.[DiscSum], 
T0.[VatSum], T0.[DocTotal], T1.[LineTotal], T0.[DocStatus]

FROM OINV T0  INNER JOIN INV1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry


 select distinct itemcode,CardCode,CardName,DocTotal,LineTotal from RIN1 , ORIN
 Select SUM (linetotal) as ARINVOICE from INV1
 Select SUM (LineTotal) as Credittotal from RIN1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following to your queries:

```
select (select) - (select);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the sums to variables and then subtract.

```
Select SUM (linetotal) INTO SUM_ONE from INV1

Select SUM (LineTotal) INTO SUM_TWO from RIN1

SELECT SUM_ONE - SUM_TWO
```

Note, my syntax may be a little off since you tagged both mysql and sql-server.  SQL Server requires its variables to start with an @.